# i want to show empty view data in recyclerview kotlin but error

Tags: android, kotlin

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            override fun onChanged() {
                super.onChanged()
                checkEmpty()
            }

            override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
                checkEmpty()
            }

            override fun onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount)
                checkEmpty()
            }

            fun checkEmpty() {
                tv_no_data.visibility = (if (adapter.itemCount == 0) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE)
            }
        })
```

adapter was error unexpected red underline how to fix it? i try use private var adapter to initialize but still red underline need help

Comment: `red underline` doesn't mean anything to anyone - what does the error say ?

Comment: private lateinit var adapter was unexpected error

Answer (score 0):

How is your variable declared?

Verify that it is correctly initialized.

for example:

```
private lateinit var adapter: CustomAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...

        adapter = CustomAdapter(this, mutableListOf())
}
```